# Turn off highlights when pattern is entered

Tags: highlight

I find `:set hlsearch` useful while I am entering the pattern; but I want the effect of `:noh` as soon as I press enter. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe `nnoremap <CR> :nohl<CR><C-L>`?

Comment: @statox: thanks! what does <c-l> do?

Comment: It redraws the screen ([`:h CTRL-L`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#CTRL-L)). Does the mapping works properly? I havent tested it so I'd like to have a confirmation before I make it an answer :-)

Comment: @statox: yes. except I discovered that multiple highlights are only showed after `<cr>`; but the mapping works with the 2nd `<cr>`.

Comment: I not sure of what 2nd `<CR>` you're talking about, now I have access to a Vim I just tested `nnoremap <CR> :nohl<CR>` (without redraw) and it seems to work properly.

Comment: I mean it only works after you pressed enter twice; but that makes sense, since you have to press it a first time for all the highlights to show.

Comment: I'm curious: did my solution not work for you? I think it should work (I've tested it), and it seems to me that it should be marked the correct answer. If not, could you explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

From a excellent book -- "Practical Vim":

> Typing `:noh<CR>` to mute search highlighting is laborious. You can
>   speed things up by creating a mapping such as this:
>
> ```
> nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :<C-u>nohlsearch<CR><C-l>
> ```
>
> Normally,  clears and redraws the screen (see `:h CTRL-L`). This
>   mapping builds on top of the usual behavior by muting search
>   highlighting.

You can add this line to you *vimrc* file. If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, Vim will mute search highlighting and redraw the screen at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve what you want through the mapping

```
cnoremap <silent> <cr> <cr>:nohl<cr>
```

The above mapping should turn of highlighted searches after you have pressed enter to accept the search pattern.

Note, though, that the highlighting is turned back on with for instance `n` and `N`, i.e. when repeating the search. You can turn this off with maps, e.g.

```
nnoremap n n:nohl<cr>
nnoremap N N:nohl<cr>
```

Note: I found that the above `cnoremap` does not work as expected if you use the [incsearch](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim) plugin, and I could not find why.

Comment: You could remap `n` with `:nnoremap n n:nohl<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

I have in my .vimrc

```
:nmap <leader>q :nohlsearch<CR>
```

which maps my leader (\ by default, but I remapped to ,) then q to remove the search highlighting.  Not exactly what you're looking for, but it might be worthwhile.

That, and several other nice bits came from http://dougblack.io/words/a-good-vimrc.html#search, though he uses space to disable the highlight.